# How to set the selected value of a KendoDropDownList with data from the database with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I am having a bit of an issue on setting the selected value of a KendoDropDownList with the ID from a database in JQuery.
When I click on a row in my grid, it gets the selected ID and returns the record for that ID and populates some fields.

This is how I am trying to set the selected value of the dropdownlist

```
    function GetDataForAdministrator(administrators) {
    CheckAdministratorPasswordStrength();
    $("#txtNewAdmin").val(administrators[0].administratorName);
    $("#txtPassword").val(administrators[0].administratorPassword);
    $("#txtConfirmPassword").val(administrators[0].administratorPassword);
    $("#txtAdministratorEmail").val(administrators[0].administratorEmail);
    $("#AdminRoles option[value='" + administrators[0].administratorRoleID + "']").attr("selected", "selected");

}
```

This worked for a normal html select, but doesn't work with the dropdown.

How do I set the selected value of the dropdownlist from the database?

Answer (score 0):

I got it figured out, I removed

```
$("#AdminRoles option[value='" + administrators[0].administratorRoleID + "']").attr("selected", "selected");
```

and replaced it with this

```
var dd = $("#AdminRoles").data("kendoDropDownList");
dd.text(administrators[0].administratorRole);
```

Now it works.